# The usage of articles

Tags: articles

Which variant is correct and why?
1.Salad is a good starter.
2. A salad is a good starter.
3. The salad is a good starter.

Comment: I wonder this as well. You most probably will be asked to add the context. Because it is hard to answer to your question without it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no context. This is a test my studrnts have to do, but I do not know the answer myself)))

Answer (score 3):

In isolation, this looks like a poorly-cast test question.

> Salad is a good starter.
>   Beef is a good starter.

Singular nouns that stand without a determiner are regarded as uncountable nouns or mass nouns.

> A salad is a good starter.
>   An appetizer is a good starter.

In contrast, singular nouns with a determiner that marks number are regarded, unsurprisingly, as countable nouns.

The word "salad" falls into both categories.  It has a countable sense that's similar to words like "appetizer" and "serving", and a uncountable sense that's similar to words like "beef" and "pork".

> The salad is a good starter.
>   The beef is a good starter.
>   The appetizer is a good starter.

Not every determiner marks number.  This "the" simply marks that something else in the context will distinguish *which* salad, beef or appetizer is the reference in question.

Unless we have something else to distinguish which semantics are more relevant, we can't tell you which grammatical form is more appropriate.